# Determine current networking manager being used on Linux

Tags: networking, networkmanager

Is there a quick and dirty way to figure out what network manager (and no, not NetworkManager) a given distro is using to manage the machine's networking? Like Ubuntu 18.04+ uses netplan, CentOS uses NetworkManager, etc. Or am I stuck having to google this on a distro to distro basis?

Comment: Netplan is not a network manager. It uses either NetworkManager or systemd-networkd. And I doubt anybody has made a comprehensive list, especially since this can be configured. You don't even have to use a network manager; even Centos 8 can be turned back to the old ifupdown.

Comment: Ubuntu ( and Debian ) uses NetworkManager by default but also has ifupdown installed by default if you want to configure /etc/network/interfaces.  Running `networkctl` will tell you whether systemd-networkd is running and managing any interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do this other than try out one by one:

```
$ systemctl status NetworkManager.service
$ systemctl status systemd-networkd.service
$ systemctl status dhcpcd.service
```

My list is definitely not complete. Also, network managers can and sometimes are supposed to run simultaneously.